Understanding the Product of Manifolds and a Manifold with Boundary
I'm reading Lee's "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds", and the author defines a atlas for a smooth n-Manifold with boundary as a collection of homeomorphisms from open sets to (relatively) open sets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ or $\mathbb{H}^n = \{(x_1, \dots, x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid x_n \geq 0\}$.
Also he defines a "product differentiable structure" for product of smooth manifolds $M_1 \times \dots \times M_k$, considering the maximal atlas induced by the atlas given by the maps $\varphi_1 \times \dots \times \varphi_k$ where $\varphi_i$ runs over the maximal atlas of $M_i$. The author does this also in case $M_k$ is actually a manifold with boundary, and explains how $M_1 \times \dots \times M_k$ is a manifold with boundary, and $\partial(M_1 \times \dots \times M_k) = M_1 \times \dots \times \partial M_k$ (proposition 1.45).
The problem comes when in proposition 3.14, he considers a product space $M_1 \times ... \times M_k$ where anyone, but only one, of the $M_i$-s is allowed to have boundary.
It seems to me that following the definition of the "product differentiable structure" one would basically try to induce a maximal atlas from a collection of maps that is not an atlas! Namely, the maps $\varphi_1 \times \dots \times \varphi_k$ map open subsets of the product space in the set $\{(x_1, \dots, x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid x_{n_1 + \dots + n_i} \geq 0\}$ (where $n_1, \dots, n_i$ are the dimensions of the first $i$ manifolds in the product).
Even if I'm right, it is clear to me that this is only an irrelevant formality, since the maps $\varphi_1 \times \dots \times \varphi_k$ actually induce the correct smooth structure, just by not requiring they being part of the atlas, but only that the atlas have to be smooth compatible with them. In this way, the maps $\Lambda (\varphi_1 \times \dots \times \varphi_k)$, where $\Lambda$ is the linear map that exchange the last coordinate with the $(n_1+\dots+n_i)$-th one, belongs to the atlas, so that the smooth structure is determined. Or also one could include in the definition of charts for manifold with boundary also maps from opens in the manifold to opens in "the $i$-th half space", that is, the set $\mathbb{H}_i^n = \{(x_1, \dots, x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid x_i \geq 0\}$, actually making $\varphi_1 \times \dots \times \varphi_k$ a smooth chart. Also one could just require $i$ to be $k$, like the author himself did in proposition 1.45 (mentioned above), again making $\varphi_1 \times \dots \times \varphi_k$ a smooth chart.
The question is then, am I right that this is a little mistake?
If I am, what is the conventionally correct way of overcoming it? One of the ways I proposed, or something else maybe?
